# Oracle update data by function regexp_*?

Tags: sql, oracle

In my table , there is a col whose data is not suitable for handle. For data like '20140101'
 i want to transform it to be '2014-01-01'. and data like '201401', i want to transform it to be '21014-01-01' and etc. i would like transform them one type by one type. First  i use

```
select regexp_replace(t.thedate, '(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '\1-\2-\3')  from item t where regexp_like(t.thedate, '\d{8}')
```

It looks good, but it doesnot update data. So how to write this sentence? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the data, you might try this:

```
UPDATE item t SET t.thedate = regexp_replace(t.thedate, '(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '\1-\2-\3') where regexp_like(t.thedate, '\d{8}')
```

Also, if you want to replace the 6 character date, you might want to do:

```
UPDATE item t SET t.thedate = regexp_replace(t.thedate, '(\d{4})(\d{2})', '\1-\2-01') where regexp_like(t.thedate, '\d{6}');
```

SQLFiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2d72/6)